# trying to Upload .rmd file to wordpress

Tags: html, r, wordpress, knitr, r-markdown

I'm having trouble uploading .rmd file to wordpress. I'm not exactly sure what's going on but the error suggests I don't have privileges to remotely publish to wordpress even though from what I understand Wordpress allows remote publishing even for free accounts. I've searched all the wordpress R queries on stack overflow and nothing seems to work. Here's my work flow:

```
devtools:::install_github("duncantl/RWordPress", force=T)
library(RWordPress)
# Set login parameters (replace admin,password and blog_url!)
options(WordPressLogin = c(admin = 'password'), WordPressURL = 'blog_url/xmlrpc.php')

library(markdown)
library(knitr)
options(markdown.HTML.options =  c(markdownHTMLOptions(default = T),"toc"))

# Upload plots: set knitr options
opts_knit$set(upload.fun = function(file){library(RWordPress);uploadFile(file)$url;})
postThumbnail <- RWordPress::uploadFile("File.rmd",overwrite = TRUE)
```

That produces the following error:

```
Error: faultCode:  401  faultString:  You do not have permission to upload files.
```

I also tried the following:

```
knit2wp('fake.rmd', title = 'TITLE', publish = FALSE)
```

And that produces the same error.

Here's my session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.1.0    rmarkdown_1.0    knitr_1.13      
[4] markdown_0.7.7   RWordPress_0.2-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5         formatR_1.4        
 [3] plyr_1.8.3          bitops_1.0-6       
 [5] base64enc_0.1-3     tools_3.3.0        
 [7] digest_0.6.10       jsonlite_1.0       
 [9] evaluate_0.9        tibble_1.1         
[11] gtable_0.2.0        viridisLite_0.1.3  
[13] lattice_0.20-33     png_0.1-7          
[15] DBI_0.4-1           mapproj_1.2-4      
[17] proto_0.3-10        gridExtra_2.2.1    
[19] dplyr_0.5.0         httr_1.2.1         
[21] stringr_1.0.0       caTools_1.17.1     
[23] RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.7 htmlwidgets_0.7    
[25] maps_3.1.0          grid_3.3.0         
[27] R6_2.1.2            jpeg_0.1-8         
[29] plotly_4.1.0        XML_3.98-1.4       
[31] RSelenium_1.4.2     RJSONIO_1.3-0      
[33] sp_1.2-3            ggmap_2.6.1        
[35] tidyr_0.5.1         reshape2_1.4.1     
[37] magrittr_1.5        XMLRPC_0.3-0       
[39] scales_0.4.0        htmltools_0.3.5    
[41] assertthat_0.1      formattable_0.2    
[43] colorspace_1.2-6    geosphere_1.5-1    
[45] labeling_0.3        stringi_1.0-1      
[47] RCurl_1.95-4.8      lazyeval_0.2.0     
[49] munsell_0.4.3       rjson_0.2.15
```

I'd also like to note, I checked the password and username and they're both correct (if I enter incorrect information I get a different error indicating that). I've also gotten a similar error trying user written functions:

```
Error: faultCode:  401  faultString:  Sorry, you are not allowed to publish posts on this site.
```

By the way, when I run `getUsersBlogs()` I get:

```
$isAdmin
[1] TRUE

$isPrimary
[1] TRUE

$url
[1] "https://blogname.wordpress.com/"

$blogid
[1] "115210981"

$blogName
[1] "Site Title"

$xmlrpc
[1] "https://blogname.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php"
```

Comment: I was having this same problem.  This post fixed the problem for me. Turned out to be a very easy fix, hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298417/knit2wp-error-doesnt-recognize-username-or-password

Comment: Been having the same Issue for quite some time now but with a different message error:
`Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.mywebpage.com:443`

Answer (score -1):

As implied by @Lloyd Christmas, the problem is with your specification of options. If you change "WordPressURL" to "WordpressURL", you'll probably be fine.